# How I can set referer for javafx mediaplayer

Tags: javafx, media-player, desktop-application, mediaview

I'm using JavaFx MediaPlayer in kotlin desktop. How I can set referer for link.
here my code:

```
        val mediaView = MediaView()
        val media =
            Media("https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8")
        val player = MediaPlayer(media)
        player.isAutoPlay = true
        mediaView.mediaPlayer = player
```